# How to bind SSH SOCKS5 proxy endpoint to a specific interface?

Tags: ssh, network-interface, routing, ssh-tunneling, socks5-proxy

I'd like to use SSH on my Windows box to setup a SOCKS5 proxy to my multi-interface pfSense box and want the proxied traffic to be routed over a specific interface on the pfSense box. The `-b` option binds the SSH client to a specific interface, is there a similar option/command to bind the server?